# Тень для Panel Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите как сделать тень для Panel/GroupBox.

Answer (score 2):

Тень придётся делать тем или иным способом ручной отрисовкой. Например, под панель можно добавить ещё одну со сдвигом.

```
var shadow = new Panel { Parent = this, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None, Top = 35, Left = 35, BackColor = Color.Black };
var panel = new Panel { Parent = this, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle, Top = 30, Left = 30 };
panel.BringToFront();
//shadow.SendToBack();
```

`BringToFront` или `SendToBack` нужно вызвать, чтобы расположить панели в правильном порядке z-index.

Можно, конечно, создать панели в режиме дизайнера. На тулбаре Layout есть кнопки Bring to Front и Send to Back.

---

В качестве цвета тени лучше всего использовать `SystemColors.ButtonShadow` - это даст хороший контраст при любой цветовой теме операционной системы.

---

При желании, вместо одной большой панели-тени такого же размера, можно добавлять две узких.